# Swift cast to array and dictionary

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, casting

I'm just now exploring Swift, converting my Objective-C classes one by one. 
Now I'm running into the following. Consider my obj-c code below

```
id messageLinks=thismessage.links;
NSDictionary *something = messageLinks[3];
NSString *messageLink =something[@"Href"];
```

This `message.links` is an Array, stored with CoreData as a Transformable.
As you can see, I need the fourth object, which is an NSDictionary, of which I need the value for a key named "Href".

Converting this to Swift causes me a lot of trouble.
First, I need to cast the Transformable message.links to an array. Guided by errors and Fix suggestions of Xcode, I ended up doing

```
let messageLinks = message.links as? Array<Any>
```

But then I get in trouble defining the intermediate 'something' as a Dictionary.

I know this is pretty elementary, but I hope someone among you could spell this out for me.

thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let linksDict = messageLinks[3] as? [String: Any] {
    let messageLink = linksDict[“Href”] as? String
}
```